# Simulation task, I'm stuck with producing correct output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been tasked with producing a simple program that simulates the actions of a vehicle from a list of command stored & accessed within a text file.

The expected output would look something like this;

```
Loading simulation...
Accelerating...
Speed = 5, Gear = 1, Direction = 0
Accelerating...
Speed = 10, Gear = 1, Direction = 0
Accelerating...
Changing up...
Current gear = 2
Speed = 15, Gear = 2, Direction = 0
Accelerating...
Speed = 20, Gear = 2, Direction = 0
Accelerating...
```

Yet my output looks like this;

```
Loading Simulation....
Car Gear is First (1)
Accelerating...
Car Gear is First (1)
Speed = 5, Gear = 1, Direction = [-1, 0, 1]
Braking...
Car Gear is First (1)
Speed = 0, Gear = 1, Direction = [-1, 0, 1]
Car Gear is First (1)
Accelerating...
Car Gear is First (1)
Speed = 5, Gear = 1, Direction = [-1, 0, 1]
Braking...
Car Gear is First (1)
Speed = 0, Gear = 1, Direction = [-1, 0, 1]
Car Gear is First (1)
```

When I run my code in Idle, i get no errors of any kind, when i use Thonny, it gives me the folloing error when it analyses the code:

```
Line 113 : Either all return statements in a function should return an expression, or none of them should.
Line 113 : Unused argument 'selected_gear'
```

Below is a copy of my code also:

```
RIGHT = 1
LEFT = -1
FORWARD = 1
REVERSE = 0
STRAIGHT = 0


#gears and allowable speeds are as follows:
    #zero (reverse) (speed -1 to -10). Max reverse speed of car is -10
    #one (speed 0 to 10)
    #two (speed 10 to 20)
    #three (speed 20 to 30)
    #four (speed 30 to 45)
    #five (speed 45 to 80). Max speed of car is 80
    #gears change automatically, one gear at a time

#direction values are similar to numbers on clock face
#0 = 12 = straight on. All other directions = 1-11

class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.speed = 0
        self.gear = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
        self.direction = [-1,0,1]
        self.broken = False #indicates whether car is broken
        self.simulation = []
        self.simulation_loaded = False

    def accelerate(self):
        if self.broken:
            print("Car is broken!")
            return
        print("Accelerating...")
        
        if self.gear == REVERSE:
            self.speed -= 5
        else:
            self.speed += 5
        
        if self.speed > 80:
            self.speed = 80
        if self.speed < -10:
            self.speed = -10

            

        self.change_gear(self.gear)
        self.display_stats()

    def brake(self):
        if self.broken:
            print("Car is broken...")
            return
        print("Braking...")
        if self.speed < 0:
            self.speed += 5
            if self.speed > 0:
                self.speed = 0
        elif self.speed > 0:
            self.speed -= 5
            if self.speed < 0:
                self.speed = 0

        self.change_gear(self.gear)
        self.display_stats()

    def turn_steering_wheel(self, direction_change):
        if self.broken:
            print("Car is broken...")
            return
        if self.gear == REVERSE:
            print ("Car is in reverse...")
            
            if direction_change == RIGHT:
                self.direction = -1
                print("Reversing Right")
            elif direction_change == REVERSE:
                self.direction = 12
                print("Reversing")
            elif direction_change == LEFT:
                self.direction = 1
                print("Reversing Left")
        
            
        elif self.gear == FORWARD:
            if direction_change == LEFT:
                self.direction = -1
                print("Turning Left")
                
            elif direction_change == STRAIGHT:
                self.direction = 0
                print("Moving Forward")
                
            elif direction_change == RIGHT:
                self.direction = 1
                print("Turning Right")
                
        
        self.display_stats()
       
    def change_gear(self, selected_gear = FORWARD):
        if self.broken:
            print("Car is broken...")
            return self.broken
#         if self.gear == 0 and self.speed >= 0:
#             print("you are going forward while in reverse gear...")
#             return self.broken    
#         elif self.gear >= 1 and self.speed <= -1:
#             print("you are going reverse while in foward gear...")
#             return self.broken
            
        if self.speed <= -1:
            self.gear = 0
            print("Car Gear is Neutral (0)")
            return self.gear
        elif self.speed <= 10:
            self.gear = 1
            print("Car Gear is First (1)")
            return
        elif self.speed <= 20:
            self.gear = 2
            print("Car Gear is Second (2)")
            return
        elif self.speed <= 30:
            self.gear = 3
            print("Car Gear is Third (3)")
            return
        elif self.speed <= 40:
            self.gear = 4
            print("Car Gear is Fourth (4)")
            return
        elif self.speed <= 50:
            self.gear = 5
            print("Car Gear is Fifth (5)")
            return
             
        self.display_stats()     
        self.change_gear(self.gear)    
        #check to see if car is going forward when reverse is selected and vice versa
            
        #work out what gear you need to be in based on car’s speed

        #Loop one gear at a time, either changing up or down, to get to required gear
        print("Changing up...")

    def display_stats(self):
        print(f"Speed = {self.speed}, Gear = {self.gear}, Direction = {self.direction}")

    def load_simulation(self, filename):
        file = open(filename)
        line = file.readline()
        while line !='':
            self.simulation.append(line.strip())
            line = file.readline()
        file.close()
        self.simulation_loaded = True
        return self.simulation

    def run_simulation(self):
        if self.simulation_loaded == False:
            print("Error - Simulation.txt file is present")
        else:
            print("Loading Simulation....")

        for action in self.simulation:
            if action == "FORWARD":
                self.change_gear (FORWARD)
            elif action == "ACCELERATE":
                self.accelerate()
            elif action == "LEFT":
                #self.direction(LEFT)
                print("TURNING LEFT")
            elif action == "RIGHT":
                #self.direction(RIGHT)
                print("TURNING RIGHT")
                '''***WHEN USING SELF.DIRECTION(LEFT)/(RIGHT) the following error is given:
                        Traceback (most recent call last):
                          File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Bsc Computer Forensics - Laptop\Software-Dev\car-temp-2.py", line 207, in <module>
                             my_car.run_simulation()
                          File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Bsc Computer Forensics - Laptop\Software-Dev\car-temp-2.py", line 183, in run_simulation
                            self.direction(LEFT)
                            TypeError: 'list' object is not callable*** '''
            elif action == "BRAKE":
                self.brake()
            else:
                self.change_gear (REVERSE)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_car = Car()
    my_car.load_simulation("simulation.txt")
    my_car.run_simulation()
```

Would I please be able to ask if anyone could explain what the errors im getting mean and where in my code I need to be looking, its got me feeling a little lost now - I've tried to research them, fix them but anyhting I try either seems to have no impact or gives errors that otherwise don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors occur in your `change_gear()` function, although they are more like warnings and should not pose serious problems:

```
Line 113 : Either all return statements in a function should return an expression, or none of them should.
```

The first two `return` statements return a value while the others don't. This is inconsistent and makes the code harder to understand. Since you don't actually use the returned values anywhere, you can remove them (i.e. use plain `return`).

```
Line 113 : Unused argument 'selected_gear'
```

You don't use the `selected_gear` argument anywhere inside `change_gear()`. You can remove it to get rid of the warning/error.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply - that helped, sometimes another perspective is all we need.

Comment: Happy to hear that! Consider upvoting and/or marking the answer as accepted if it helped you.